# Can two standing waves combine to form a traveling wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, vibrations

Two traveling waves with equal and opposite wave-vectors form a standing wave, which is easy to prove.

But what about combining two standing waves?

Can we derive the velocity of the wave/disturbance created by combining two standing waves?

For example take two standing waves:

$$ y_1(x,t)=A_1sin(k_1x)cos(\omega_1t) $$
$$ y_2(x,t)=A_2sin(k_2x)cos(\omega_2t) $$

And combine them:

$$y(x,t)=y_1+y_2$$

Does this result in a traveling wave? If so, what is its wave-vector and velocity?

Comment: Let $k_1=k_2,\omega_1=\omega_2, A_2=iA_1$

Comment: How do you “prove” two equal and opposite waves superposed form a standing wave? To me that is a definition

Answer (score 3):

By this [trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)
$$
\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\sin\beta
$$
the two standing waves
\begin{align}
y_1(x,t)&=\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)\,,\quad y_2(x,t)=\cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)
\end{align}
form the travelling wave
$$
y(x,t)=\sin(kx+\omega t)\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In general adding two standing waves can't create a traveling wave.

To see this we could look at the amplitude of the resultant wave.  That is obtained by adding the amplitudes of the standing waves at each point.

A traveling wave has equal amplitude of oscillation for each part of the wave, but at $A$ the amplitude is the same as that of the green standing wave.  At $B$ the amplitude is the same (or lower) than that of the red standing wave.

[image]

That would mean that the amplitude at $A$ was greater than that at $B$, so unless there were some very particular conditions met (perhaps as in RoderickLee's comment), then the traveling wave wouldn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$k_1 = k_2 = k_3$$
$$\omega_1 = \omega_2 = \omega_3$$
$$A_1 = A_2 = A_3$$
$$\phi_1 = 0, \space \phi_2 = 2\pi/3, \space \phi_3 = 4 \pi/3$$

Comment: Do you mean it can be done by adding three standing waves?  Could you explain what you mean by this please?