# A standing wave may be expressed as superposition traveling waves - is the converse, traveling as superposition of standing, also true?

Tags: waves, acoustics, fourier-transform, frequency, mathematics

So I consider the wave equation:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_2^2} + \cdots + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_n^2}\right)
\end{align*}

defined on $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ with boundary condition $u = 0$.

My intuition is that there are some eigenfunctions $u_k(t=0)$ such that the "acceleration" of the displacement is proportional to the displacement, which is exactly the definition of a standing wave; and that these eigenfunctions span the space of all possible $u(t = 0)$.

I tried to visualize this theory in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/arphxk7igy (press play on $t$)

But it looks very unnatural. Is there something wrong with my method?

Comment: I believe you could formulate a "standing wave solution" to your problem by using the Fourier Transform to create the shape of the travelling wave with standing waves although I haven't tried it myself. What is very impractical in this case is that you would have to calculate different standing waves (and/or coefficients) for each time instant since the wave is travelling and waves with constant amplitude envelope cannot "follow" the movement of the travelling wave.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is [yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/743010/304394), despite someone over there denying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, in fact, decomposing into stationary modes a linear problem is a very standard approach to solving the Cauchy problem. In your case, you forgot that the full Cauchy problem (temporal initial conditions) is given by $u(t=0):=u_0(x)$ and $\partial_tu(t=0):=v_0(x)$. In general, “all” solutions can be expressed as a superposition of stationary modes:
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{m\in (\mathbb N^*)^n}(A_m\cos(k_mt)+B_m\sin(k_mt))\sin(k_mx)
$$
where:
$$
\begin{align}
k_m &= \pi m\\
A_m &= 2^n\int u_0(x)\sin(k_mx)d^nx\\
B_m &= \frac{2^n}{k_m}\int v_0(x)\sin(k_mx)d^nx
\end{align}
$$

Intuitively, your wave equation describes traveling waves. With your Dirichlet boundary conditions, these waves are reflected at the boundary. All of this is captured in this stationary mode decomposition.

Btw, if you don’t want reflections, you’ll need to rather study the domain of the entire space $\mathbb R^3$. In this case, the formula is almost the same, you just need to replace the sum by an integral and the wavevectors are now continuous.

Hope this helps.